# In "Resolution", where did the Dalek get remnants of its original shell?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode "Resolution", it is stated the Dalek rebuilt itself from spare parts patched up with remnants of its original casing. After the Dalek awakens we see it go to a weapons facility to retrieve its gun, and it also loads another crate (presumably the missiles seen later on), and right after that it goes to the farm to build its casing.

Where did it get pieces of its old shell? I doubt seemingly random pieces of metal would be kept in a weapons facility.

Comment: Why not? The Dalek shell is a weapon in its own regard, since it can shock people and contains missiles

Comment: I was under the impression the missiles weren't a function of its original casing (since we've never seen them before in any other Dalek) and they were implemented just then so the Dalek could safely get to GCHQ. They didn't look very Dalek in design

Comment: And as for shocking people, is that stated in this episode? I'm pretty sure that was a Time War thing since it wasn't in classic Who, and this Dalek originates from long before the War

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the episode's prologue, it is explained that the Dalek's remains were entrusted to three persons known as the *Three Custodians*. We later learn that the descendants of these three individuals were tasked with ensuring that the three Dalek parts were never reunited - these descendants were known as *the Order of the Custodians*.

When the Dalek took control of a host body, it used the internet to research where it could find Dalek parts. On the laptop screen, we see that it researches Unit's *Black Archive* and also an active weapons research company named *MDZ*.

The Order of Custodians had learned that MDZ was buying up pieces of alien tech that had come onto the black market. It was these items that the Dalek obtained from MDZ's storage facility and rebuilt his case. MDZ was no ordinary weapons facility, and a Dalek's polycarbide battle armour would be as much interest to a weapons research company as an offensive weapon.

You are correct that the Doctor declares that the Dalek has built its shell from "remnants of its original shell, patched up with all sorts of spare parts. Mainly metal". It would seem that after the Dalek's real body was cut into three, some parts of its casing and weaponry had fallen into the wrong hands and ended up being bought by MDZ centuries later. Alternatively, it is possible that the Doctor was just generalising, and that the parts had come from other Dalek encounters, not necessarily this particular one.

This last part is a little speculative - but given that the episode reveals that at this point in time, UNIT operations have been "suspended pending review", it is *possible* that UNIT had been infiltrated or compromised in some way since we last heard of them. This might explain why items that ought to have been in their archives had fallen onto the black market.